# Debug in visual code studio is giving error. Why?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am getting this error and debug is not working. Debug in visual code studio is giving an error. Why?

[image]

[image]

```
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

c:\Users\dino_\Desktop\python_lessons>C:\Users\dino_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe c:\Users\dino_\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.10.44104\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py --default --client --host localhost --port 51656 c:\Users\dino_\Desktop\python_lessons\itertools.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\dino_\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.10.44104\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 21, in <module>
    import ptvsd
  File "c:\Users\dino_\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.10.44104\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ._vendored import force_pydevd
  File "c:\Users\dino_\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.10.44104\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\force_pydevd.py", line 18, in <module>
    pydevd_constants = import_module('_pydevd_bundle.pydevd_constants')
  File "C:\Users\dino_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "c:\Users\dino_\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.10.44104\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_constants.py", line 205, in <module>
    from _pydev_imps._pydev_saved_modules import thread
  File "c:\Users\dino_\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.10.44104\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydev_imps\_pydev_saved_modules.py", line 21, in <module>
    import xmlrpc.client as xmlrpclib
  File "C:\Users\dino_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 135, in <module>
    from decimal import Decimal
  File "C:\Users\dino_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\decimal.py", line 3, in <module>
    from _decimal import *
AttributeError: module 'numbers' has no attribute 'Number'
```

Internal error detected. Please copy the above traceback and report at
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/new

Press Enter to close. . .

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely because you have a file named `numbers.py` which is shadowing what's in the standard library; same goes for `itertools`. Make sure to not name modules with the same name as things in Python's stdlib and you will avoid this issue.